# Popover Bootstrap: сделать возможным клик по элементу div#pop

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать возможным клик по элементу div#pop:

```
<a rel="popover" class="subscribes_category" data-content="<div id="pop"></div>">Категория</a>
```

Т-е на id="pop" привязано событие click, которое не срабатывает.

Comment: Маразм крепчал. Как вы думаете, где тут открывающие кавычки, а где — закрывающие?

    data-content="<div id="pop"></div>"

Comment: И ещё вопрос. `<div id="pop"></div>` — это не элемент (не часть `DOM`-дерева), а просто значение атрибута `data-content` ссылки. Предоставьте код, который создаёт этот элемент с соответствующего атрибутаю

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разберитесь с кавычками:

```
... data-content="<div id='pop'></div>" ...
```

Ну а далее попробуйте так если используете jQuery:

```
$('#pop').click(function(){
    // Клик случился...
});
```

Comment: Даже так не работает: <a rel="popover" class="subscribes_category" data-content="<div id='pops'>ssssssss</div>" >Категория</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="popover_click" rel="popover" data-content="<div id='pop'></div>" data-original-title="Заголовок"></div>

$(function () { 
    $(".popover_click[rel=popover]").popover({trigger: 'click'});
});
```

Comment: И как этим пользоваться? т-е что дает trigger?

Comment: Мне клик нужно сделать по элементу внутри popover

Answer (score 0):

видимо нужно копать в сторону .on()
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});// это пример из API JQuery
браузер ничего не знает о существовании div с id='pop'. событие нужно вешать на родителя